# Array c++ explanation

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I am a bit confused with arrays. I have tried searching them up, but I haven't found the answer I want.

Confused about arrays like this :

```
Item **queue;
```

Does that mean item is creating a 2d array for queue? And what would the array look like? Please give me a brief explanation covering all this. Thank you

Comment: That is not an array, that is a pointer to a pointer to an Item.

Comment: From what I heard. 2 pointers are a 2d array. One meaning a pointer to queue and the other meaning an array

Comment: 2d arrays are declared as `que[10][20]` -- but you cannot use them in connection with a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: bookmark this site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

Comment: @Soren What are you talking about? A duplicate? The questions are totally different. What do you mean?

Comment: @user6091183 -- The questions goes deeper than yours in explaining the difference between `**` and `[][]` and the answers (which I assume you have read) goes deeper explaining the memory layout differences -- so your right, your question is a subset and not strictly a duplicate

Comment: @Soren I think you have a complete misundertsanding. This is the only question I've asked about arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
Item **queue;
```

It is not an array. It is a pointer to a pointer to an Item. You can use it to refer to a memory location that contains an array of pointers to Items.

> Does that mean item is creating a 2d array for queue?

No. No array is created when you declare a pointer to a pointer. You just create a pointer which *might* refer to a 2d array. The creation of the 2d array is up to the developer.

This is an example how you could initialise the queue:

```
int main()
{
  Item * array_1 = new Item[2]; // array of Items
  Item * array_2 = new Item[2]; // array of Items
  Item * array_3 = new Item[2]; // array of Items
  Item ** queue = new Item*[3]; // array of pointers 

  queue[0] = array_1;
  queue[1] = array_2;
  queue[1] = array_3;

  delete queue[0];
  delete queue[1];
  delete queue[1];
  delete queue;
}
```

Note, I use the operator `new` in C++ to create a 2d array in the heap.

Comment: I initialized by saying queue = New Item *[maxNumItems];

Comment: does that still not make it an array?

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided

```
Item **queue;
```

is not an array, but a pointer-to-a-pointer, however you can assign an address of an array to the pointer (as you can with any pointer).

So somebody creating an array like

```
Item* queues[100]; // An array of pointer to Item
```

and you can assign the pointer to a pointer, for example

```
Item* queues[100]; // An array of pointer to Item
Item **queuepointers;

// .. assume that the queues pointers is allocated by some code here...
// ... then
queuepointers = queues;  
queues[50]->someMethodInItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation about variables, pointers and arrays.

In C++, **variables** are stored in memory. Data in memory have values and addresses. CPUs don't know variable names, they only know memory addresses. When you compile your code, the compiler (actually, the linker) changes the variable name (a.k.a. symbol) to the actual memory address allocated for that variable. So when you retrieve the value of a variable in code, what actually happen is telling CPU the address, and CPU retrieve the data stored in that address of memory.

Addresses are just 32-bit or 64-bit (based on your CPU architecture) unsigned integers. So variables can also contain the addresses of other variables, which is called **pointers**. Pointers are also variables, the only difference is that pointers are 32-bit or 64-bit unsigned integers whose data is the address of other places.

When you declare a variable like `float *a`, that means `a` is a pointer to a variable of type `float`. So the value of `a` is not float number, but an unsigned integer. To change the location where `a` is pointing at, just assign value to `a` like `a = &my_float_var;`. Notice that I use `&` to get the address of variable `my_float_var`.

As for **array**s, they are just multiple variables allocated adjacent to each other. For example, we declare an array `int arr[10]`, and say the address of the first element `arr[0]` is `100`, then the address of second element `arr[1]` is `104` (an `int` is 4 bytes, address is measured in bytes). If you put `arr` without bracket in code, that means the address of the array, i.e. the address of the first element.

You can see that arrays and pointers are similar. You can declare char arrays like:

```
char str1[] = "some string";
char *str2  = "some string";
```

Both method is fine. Only `str1` is a symbol and you can't alter its value (the location where it's pointing at), but you can change `str2`'s value, making it pointing to another string.

Back to your question, `Item **queue` can be though as a pointer of type `Item *`, or an array of type `Item *`. And type `Item *` can be pointer of type `Item`, or array of type `Item`.

So if `queue` is an array of type `Item *`, while each element of that array points to another array of type `Item`, `queue` can be thought of a 2d array. But that's different from conventional 2d arrays. Conventional 2d array use syntax of `arr[1,2]` to access elements, but accessing `queue`'s element should use `queue[1][2]`.